# Efficient means of drawing a lined border for a solid shape

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I currently have the following vertex data (for a pyramid) laid out like so:

```
float4 vertexData[ 18 ] =
{
    // front

    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },  // front right
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },  // top
    { -1.0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },  // front left


    // right

    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },   // right front
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },   // top
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },  // right back


    // back

    { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },  // back right
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },   // top
    { -1.0, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },  // back left


    // left

    { -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },  // left back
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },    // top
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },   // left front

    // bottom back major

    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },   // bottom left front
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },  // bottom left back
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },   // bottom right back

    // bottom front major

    { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f },   // bottom right back
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },    // bottom right front
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },   // bottom left front

};
```

I'd like to basically take my pyramid, and use shaders (if possible) to compute the edges between two vertices and then send what would be a "line" of sorts to the fragment shader.

I know I could probably just use "GL_LINES", and set a new uniform color, but I would think this wouldn't be very efficient. Maybe I'm wrong, though?

Either way, the main reason why I was originally thinking shaders is because they'd be a cool means of doing this: I could write a program which could add some interesting effects for the borders. In terms of how to do this via one shader program, though, I'm completely stumped.

Any ideas on a good approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call is cel-shading. One of the most popular tutorials for this can be found here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/cel_shading/25001/

Using GL_LINES is not inefficient. Use a VBO to store the vertex data on the GPU, then you can draw several times. And you could even draw the GL_LINES with your custom shader. In the tutorial it is basically done the same way. For the contours to not bleed into the solid object backgrounds you need a small depth offset (avoid z-buffer fighting).

Answer (score 1):

it is definetely related to cartoon (cell) shading.

There are several ways to do it:

- use geometry shaders (like here http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/1644/sponsored_feature_inking_the_.php)
- do a postprocessing like here: http://xnameetingpoint.weebly.com/shader7f31.html
- interesting method (distant to edges): http://cgg-journal.com/2008-2/06/index.html